# Weird Issue with Filename Pattern Matching

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, dataframe

I am trying to loop through several files in a folder, merge the similar files into one single data frame, and then push that object to a table in SQL Server.  I got the code working fine, for if files in one folder are all similar, but if files are different, it doesn't work.  I want to do pattern matching, based on file names, and merge those similar files into a data frame, and finally, push that object to a table in SQL Server. Then, I need to loop to the next set of files and do the same.  Here is my code.  I think it's close, but something is not quite right here.

```
import urllib
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import os, glob
from pandas import DataFrame
import os, glob
import pandas as pd

list = ['FFIEC CDR Call Bulk POR',
        'FFIEC CDR Call Schedule CI',
        'FFIEC CDR Call Schedule ENT',
        'FFIEC CDR Call Schedule GCI',
        'FFIEC CDR Call Schedule GI']

for item in list:
    
    path = "C:\\Users\\ryans\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\schemas\\"
    
    fullpath = path + item + '*'
    print(fullpath)
    all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(fullpath, "*.txt"))
    print(all_files)
    
    all_df = []
    for f in all_files: 
       df = pd.read_csv(f, delimiter='\t', skiprows=1) 
       df['thefile'] = os.path.basename(f)
       all_df.append(df) 
    
    df_append = pd.concat(all_df, ignore_index=True, sort=True)
    my_list = list(df_append)
    
    # convert the list to a data frame
    df_append = DataFrame(df_append)
    df_append.shape
    
    df_append.columns = df_append.columns.str.replace(',', '')
    df_append.columns = df_append.columns.str.replace('(', '')
    df_append.columns = df_append.columns.str.replace(')', '')
    df_append.columns = df_append.columns.str.replace(' ', '_')
    df_append.columns = df_append.columns.str.replace('.', '_')
    df_append.columns = df_append.columns.str.replace('-', '_')
    df_append.columns = df_append.columns.str.replace('/', '_')
    df_append.columns = df_append.columns.str.replace('&', '_')
    df_append.columns = df_append.columns.str.replace(':', '')
    
    # load to DB table
    engine = "mssql+pyodbc://Server_Name/DB_Name?driver=SQL Server Native Client 11.0?trusted_connection=yes"
    df_append.to_sql(item, engine, index=False, if_exists='append')
```

When I print the 'fullpath' variable, I get this kind of result.

```
C:\Users\ryans\OneDrive\Desktop\schemas\FFIEC CDR Call Subset of Schedules 3*
```

The first set of file names look like this:
FFIEC CDR Call Bulk POR 03312001.txt
FFIEC CDR Call Bulk POR 03312002.txt
etc.

The next set look like this.
FFIEC CDR Call Schedule CI 03312001.txt
FFIEC CDR Call Schedule CI 03312002.txt

There are over 400 files here, so I want to do this in some kind of automated fashion.  Thank you!!

Comment: When you print `all_files`, does it give you what you expect?

Comment: No. 'all_files' is this: []

I think the 'fullpath' variable is the issue.

Comment: try using `os.path.join` for creating fullpath, see if that helps?